# laravel 5.6 "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when trying to add condition inside mapWithKeys callback

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables: users, groups, messages;

user table is the default table generated by php artisan make:auth, Groups table contain:

id, book_id

messages table contain:

id, group_id, from, msg_content

and there is many to many relation between users table and groups table, the pivot table conatain:

user_id, group_id, last_id_seen

now I want to fetch all groups that belongs to the user and the last message from each group without null in form:
goup_id=>last_msg

so I tried:

```
 $Groups=Auth::user()->groups()->where()->get();
    $get=$Groups->mapWithKeys(function($Groups){
            $lsi=$Groups->pivot->last_id_seen;

            $istrue=$Groups->messages()->where('id','>',$lsi)->get()->isNotEmpty();
            if($istrue==true){
            return [$Groups->id => $Groups->messages()->get()->last()];
        }
        });
```

But I get the following error:

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

I Idintified where is the error exaclty it happen when if is false then it should proceed to other instruction but I can not find the right instructio I tried: return, return true, return "" but nothing worked

I am new to laravel would you healp me please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to overwrite `$Groups` by declaring it in the anonymous function, I've renamed it to `$Group` below.

Additionally, you must return something in that anonymous function. We can solve that by using [`filter()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter).

```
$Groups = Auth::user()->groups()->where()->get();

$get = $Groups->filter(function ($Group) {
    $lsi = $Group->pivot->last_id_seen;

    return $Group->messages()->where('id', '>', $lsi)->get()->isNotEmpty()
})->mapWithKeys(function ($Group) {
    return [$Group->id => $Group->messages()->get()->last()];
});
```

When you have a function that does not `return` something, its return value will be `null` which isn't valid input for `foreach`. It's expecting an `array` to be returned.

Comment: trying your solution gives the error:
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::where(), 0 passed in /home/bassel/book_donation/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate
/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php on line 369 and at least 1 expected

and when reomving when() I get:
"Illegal operator and value combination."

Comment: my mistake: when I remove when I get the same error:
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully adding the `filter()` works